# How can I Identify class with attribute Name?

Tags: c#, serialization, reflection, attributes

EmailMessage class

```
[SomeAttribute("email")]
[DataContract]
public class EmailMessage
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Message belongs to Queue Name email. I want to have some attribute of EmailMessage class which can contain queue name.
And whenever I will have object I should be able to identify message belongs to which queue and what is its categoryTypeId

Given the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QueueInfos>
<Queue>
    <CategoryTypeId>1</CategoryTypeId>
    <QueueName>email</QueueName>
    <MaxThreadCount>1</MaxThreadCount>
</Queue>
```

```
static void main()
{
   var message = new EmailMessage();
}
```

Comment: I do not understand what the title has to do with the content, especially the XML.

Comment: Xml and attribute have queue name common. So basically I want to identify queue and read other things from queue tag of xml

Comment: that does not make a lot of sense.  `SomeAttribute` is only ever going to be "email" .

Comment: I can have more queues and classes.